# Identify years with identical days of the week (e.g. 1994, 2005, 2011)

Tags: algorithm, calendar, date

I have an idea for a story in which certain events happen repeatedly throughout the year of calendar dates that perfectly match each other for example 2011, 2005, 1994 one could replace these calendars with each other 
I would like to be able to find calendar years past and future

If someone could help me please as I have no programming ability 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Outside of the leap year oddity when `year%100==0` but `year%400!=0`, the cycle repeats every 28 years.  So you can figure out which years in 2000-2027 match up, and then start changing by multiples of 28 until you get to 1900 or 2100.

Answer (score 3):

[Check Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_year_starting_on_Saturday).

Answer (score 2):

You only need to compare the day of the week on which the first day of the year falls, and compare leap years and non-leap years separately (they will obviously differ). If the first day is the same and the days in the year are the same, so will the whole year be the same.

With this reduction, we need to first know what is a leap year. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm), the algorithm is

```
if year modulo 400 is 0
       then is_leap_year
else if year modulo 100 is 0
       then not_leap_year
else if year modulo 4 is 0
       then is_leap_year
else
       not_leap_year
```

Then we need to calculate the first day of the year. Before we start, we need a grounding. Let's take 2000, which starts on a Saturday. Every year we move forward, we move forward one day in the week except if the year follows a leap year in which case we move forward two days.

Let's walk through an example. 2000 starts on Saturday. 2001 starts on a Monday, 2 days later because 2000 is a leap year. 2002 starts on Tuesday. 2003 on a Wednesday. 2004 on a Thursday. 2005 on a Saturday, because 2004 is a leap year. From this we see that 2000 and 2005 start on the same day of the week, but the one is a leap year while the other is not. If we continue we'll find 2011 starts on a Saturday, and is therefore identical to 2005.

We can work backwards in similar fashion to find years in the past, or we can just choose an earlier starting year.

Answer (score 0):

Dominical letter B: ... 1910 1921 1927 1938 1949 1955 1966 1977 1983 **1994 2005 2011** 2022 2033 2039 2050 2061 2067 2078 2089 2095 ...

Comment: these numbers are exactly what I am looking for however I came to you guys hoping to get something that I could plug dates in until i find ones that work for the story

Comment: I would like to be able to enter historical dates (years} and then research the output dates to build the story line around
I wanted an app so I could quickly and efficiently generate  and evaluate these dates
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about going back before 1752 and 1582, where 11 and 10 days were dropped from the calendar, respectively.  see dataandtime.com.  Otherwise there are exactly 14 possible calendars ... Half with a Feb 29th, half without.  Each pair of calendars starts on a different day of the week.  There should be an excel spreadsheet out there (its easy enough to generate one) that maps the years since 1752 into one of 14 columns.

Answer (score 0):

2016 ends on the same days of the week as 1994, 2005 and 2011, but 2016 starts on Friday (leap year), while all the other years start on Saturday, therefore we need to wait until 2022 before the dates in 2011 match up again.